# How can I get an object inside an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a for loop and I would like to tap into an object inside the array I am looping. Specifically I would like to tap into the "Name" section of my objects to only console.log the names, not the whole array. This is the code... I am doing this with Mongoose but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem, I just wanted to add it tho.

```
    const newCustomerNum2 = new customerList({
    name: "John",
    age: 32
    });


customerList.find(function(err, customers) {
if (err) {
 console.log(err);
} else {

for (var i = 0; i<customers.length; i++){
     console.log(customers.name);
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in your `for` loop, is that you are looping over the indices of your array.
Let's say you array has 3 elements, the `for` loop would be called with `i = 0`, then `i = 1`, then `i = 2`.

This index can be used to reference an object in your array.

When you are calling `customers.name` you are trying to access the property `name` on the array rather than the data in it.
If you want to access the objects inside your array, use the subscript expression:

`customers[i]` where `0 < i < customers.length`.

That way, you can use `console.log(customers[i].name)` in your loop.

In addition, you could simply use the `for ... of` expression, which iterates over the elements of an array:

```
for (let customer of customers) {
    console.log(customer.name);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That was a very quick answer. I just tried it and it fixed the issue. I appreciate you getting out of your way and helping people that are learning and don't have the knowledge you have.

Comment: Great ! You are welcome, we've all been there, let's make it easier for the others :).